# How to deploy the Glassware Starter Project using Google App Engine with the Go Runtime Environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-glass, google-mirror-api

Using the guide located here: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/quickstart/go I attempted to register and deploy an instance of the quickstart located here https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-go

I had some errors when I first tried to appcfg.py --oauth2 update same as identified in a google groups thread I can't post here because I'm only allowed 2 links since I don't have 10 reputation points and was able to resolve them using the 'dirty' symlinking method recommended by 'adam' in that thread.

Finally getting it to actually update successfully, when I navigate to myappname dot appspot dot com, it displays the normal login screen, and after logging in, the 'This app would like to' page, and when I click on 'Accept' it just redirects back to that same 'This app would like to' page.

What additional steps do I need to take to properly deploy the sample quickstart app on my google app engine url?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you did to get the "appcfg.py --oauth2" command to work? I'm stuck with this error: attachment.go:21: can't find import: "code.google.com/p/google-api-go-client/mirror/v1"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your app is uploaded properly and running (or else you wouldn't even be asked for a login screen).

There's two possibilities:

- Something's wrong with Google's login system.  If this is the case, it should be transient and should get fixed by Google folks.
- There's something wrong with your page and it's not handling the login properly.  Check for errors in your App Engine Admin Logs page, and see if there's any weird failures or redirects going on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the log hint. I was able to use errors in the log to track down another developer with the same problem as well as a solution (and great explanation of how to troubleshoot errors on this platform). Posting the link in case it's useful to anyone else: http://blog.sohjsolwin.com/2013/10/helpouts-meetups-and-mirror-qucikstart.html